# TFS - How to work with multiple computers on same workspace without checking in my code everyday

Tags: tfs, version-control, collaboration

I work both from the office and at home, using separate computers. Currently, to be able to continue coding from home, I need to check in all my code before leaving the office. Is there any way of making my workspace work completely online, so that I can continue my work from home without checking-in anything when I'm leaving the office?

I'm currently trying a trick; mapping my workspace on a shared folder (network drive) which I can also access from home via VPN too. But it's taking too long to even download the latest version of the project. Even if this works, I don't think it will be an efficient way because of network speed limitations.

Is there any solution for multiple computers, one user and one workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using TFVC rather than Git for source control in TFS, then you can shelve your changes rather than checking them in.

Got to the Pending changes area of Team Explorer and click on the shelve drop down.
[image: Pending Changes window]

You now have a couple of options. You must add a name then you can select

1. preserve pending change locally. This allows you to keep your
   changes in the machine you're currently working on.
2. Evaluate policies and notes. This is only necessary of you have check in
   policies set up and it can be ignored if you just want to store your
   changes as they are not complete and applying policies at this time
   might be inappropriate

[image: Shelve changes window]

Once you have done this then hit shelve. You changes are now stored on the server. When you get to your other machine go in to "Pending Changes" and select the Actions drop down and select "Find Shelevesets"

[image: Pending Changes Window]

This will present a list of shelvesets committed by you. You can search for shelvesets by other users but in this case the most recent shelveset created by you should be at the top of the list.

[image: Find Shelvesets window]

Right click on the appropriate shelveset and select "unshelve". You should now be able to continue working where you left off.

Comment: Thank you for this in-detail answer. I will try this today before leaving work. But should I leave "preserve pending changes locally" option checked or not? From what it says, it sounds like I should un-check it to be able to access the work I left at the office from home??

Comment: In your context it makes sense to uncheck it, either way it won’t stop you from accessing the shelveset but it might make resuming work easier when you return to the office

Comment: When creating Shelveset you said "You changes are not stored on the server.". How could I pull them on my other machine if they are not on the server??? :\

Comment: Typo, should have read "now stored" fixed in an edit